# How to fix weird lightmapping in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

So, I've been working on my android Unity project and ran into a problem with lightmapping. After baking lightmap, instead of getting nice and smooth light I've got this weird noisy texture over walls and floor. I tried to change lighting settings (increase/decrease resolution, toggle different parametrs, etc.) - the problem is still here. Tried to switch platform to PC - no result, it's the same. Now i ran out of any ideas. Is there any ways to fix it?
Using Unity 2018.3
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0oLQo.png)
Light parametrs:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIHOr.png)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gB4Y.png)

Answer (score 1):

If using the "progressive" lightmapper, increasing sample count usually proportionally decreases the noisiness of it;

If using Englihten, you can try the "denoising" option (see [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LightmappingSettings.html)).

Adding a screenshot of your lightmapper settings to the question could also be a good idea.

Comment: Tried to increase sample count - there is small improvment, but not really. Denoising doesn't change anything at all. Added screenshots to the post.

Answer (score 0):

In baking settings you need to choose in "Filtering" option "Auto" or "Advanced" if you want, but "Auto" should be good.